# Enabled push notification certificate now says "Configurable"

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification

I've noticed that recently when registering for notifications, new device tokens are not getting sent to my server. Note that push notifications are still being sent to devices where I have the device token, I just don't seem to be receiving new/updated tokens.

When I go to "App IDs" in the Provisioning Portal, Push Notification for my App ID in Production says "Configurable". However, when click "Configure", the Production Push SSL Certificate says "Enabled", and it doesn't expire until April 2013.

I used the "codesign" utility to look at some recent archives that have been submitted to the App Store, and I see that the older ones have aps-environment set to "production", while the newer ones have no aps-environment entitlement.

Can anyone think of why the certificate would be missing from the profile? Should I generate a new push SSL certificate even though the old one hasn't expired?

Any help is appreciated!